# SQL Azure Data Bricks

Tags: apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

We have a table 1 Day table aggregated with group by

```
call_date
,tdlinx_id
,work_request_id
,category_name
```

another table we have 1 week level data aggregated with group by

```
week_end_date
,category_name
,sdo_reporting_name
```

How can I populate the data from day level to week level ???

```
week_end_date =  date_add(call_date, 7-dayofweek(call_date))
```

Answer (score 0):

what you need is the following functions:

```sql
    SELECT current_date() + 7 - dayofweek(current_date());
```

So, In your case, it would be:

```sql
    SELECT call_date + 7 - dayofweek(call_date)
    FROM your_table;
```